# ASP.NET MVC datetime picker jQueryui

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have an issue with ASP.Net MVC Datetime picker using JQueryUI.

I am using jQuery 1.10.2 and JQueryUI 1.10.4 both obtained via Nuget Package Manager.

I have also called the jQueryUI and CSS files in BundleConfig, along with calling Script.Render(..) for them both too.

_Layout

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

BundleConfig

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));


 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

in my view I am calling

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#txtdatepicker").datepicker();
});
```

```
<p>
    @Html.TextBox("Datepicker", "", new { @id = "txtdatepicker", @style = "width:150px;" })
    <br />
    Your selected date :@ViewBag.DateValue
    <br /><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
```

However this simply isnt working an I have no idea what or where I am going wrong.

I have looked all over and see that this has been a similar issue, but none of the solutions I have tried have worked.

When I build and run the site, the view with the datetime picker textbox, making it active does not render the control.

I am using .Net 4.5, VS2015, JQuery 1.10.

It is probably something really simple, however I am just not getting it.

Thank you

Comment: Is there any error in the browser console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function(anonymous function) @ Index:131jQuery.Callbacks.fire @ jquery-1.10.2.js:3062jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith @ jquery-1.10.2.js:3174jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery-1.10.2.js:447completed @ jquery-1.10.2.js:118

Comment: This means you try to create instance of the datepicker **before** including the jQueryUI script. To solve your issue add link to the jQueryUI at first, next init datepicker.

Comment: the @script.Render() is being called in the _Layout.cshtml page and I have tried calling that before I run the script too.

Comment: `<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js"></script>


<script>
$(function () {
    $("#txtdatepicker").datepicker();
});
</script>
<p>
    <input id="txtdatepicker" name="Datepicker" style="width:150px;" type="text" value="" />
    <br />
    Your selected date :
    <br /><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</p>`

Comment: Have you tried to use `~/Scripts/...` instead of `/Scripts`? Anyway, check my solution https://www.dropbox.com/s/nxq6iz2j1t18912/datepicker.zip?dl=0, hope it helps.

Comment: Have you viewed the source on your page in the browser to make sure only 1 jquery-ui js file is there? If it includes both the regular version and the minified version it can break and show this message.

Comment: yes, there is only one reference which is this <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: that is being rendered from this @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

Comment: also used in bundleconfig here  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

Comment: Is your @Scripts.Render in the head? Wont work if it is in the footer, in the body after your .datepicker() call.

Comment: yea, its in the head

Comment: i do have this in the footer though
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: whatever I try I am having the same issue.

Comment: If you have `<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/…` at the bottom of the page, your now loading another copy of jquery and wiping out the `jquery-ui` script.

Comment: I will move these up to the top and see how that works.

Comment: @stephen Mueke can you put that as an answer so that I can officially accept it please.

Comment: I cant until you update your question to show that you have the second script in your view - need to answer the question - not comments :)